# Android - The method setText() is changing text of a widget even though it is never called

Tags: java, android, side-effects

I have a basic block of code here with simple data passing between activities. Basically when there is data received, change the text of the button:

```
Bundle intentData = getIntent().getExtras();     
if (intentData != null) {
    String passedMsg = intentData.getString("userMsg");
    Button mainButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.main_button);
    mainButton.setText(passedMsg);
}
```

However, even on cases when the if conditional fails, the text of the button still changes. When I comment out the line `mainButton.setText(passedMsg);`, the text of the button remains unchanged.

It seems as though the presence of `setText()` alters the button's text regardless of whether that line of code is reached. Why does it do this?

Comment: It absolutely does not.  Either something someplace else is setting the text, or you're incorrect about the direction the if takes.

Comment: are you sure the "if" statements fails? did you add some `Log.d` calls inside the "if" body?

Comment: So doing some Log calls confirms that the if statement doesn't fail. It seems `null` isn't passed to intentData

Comment: You should instead check if the intent has an extra with that key, not whether the extras are null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, your block of code is being executed multiple times. to prove this, do something like

```
static boolean initialized = false;

public void enteredBlockOfCode() {
     if(!initialized) {

            // code here only runs once ...

        initialized = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either the condition you're checking is not the one you should be checking, or in the code you've compiled the if statement is immediately followed by a semicolon before the braces.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `intentData` isn't ever passed `null` and so the if statements don't fail